# find where the msbuld property comes from

Tags: msbuild

I'm sorry if this question has already been asked, but I really could not anything like this.

I have to contribute to a very big project, with lots of includes and conditional assignments. I would like to know where it is being set.

More specifically, for a property NAME I would like to see in log all places where it is being assigned: project files, included files from system, builtin defaults, of any other sources.

I have tried to enable verbosity=diagnostic, but it still did not log this information.

Comment: If no other answer comes up the only solution might be to debug the msbuild process step-by-step: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/07/06/debugging-msbuild-script-with-visual-studio.aspx

Comment: For msbuild 12.0 (Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 12.0.30501.0) and vs2013 update 2 I don't see the project itself in the source debugger, so this is quite challenging to make some use of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to flatten the project using `/preprocess:flattened.proj` and then load that into a text editor and search for all uses etc.

The program MSBuildExplorer3 will give a chart showing properties and the expression used to set them, etc.  I've not used it much but that looks interesting.

It's also important to understand the order of evaluation.  Global properties are set in the order they are found in that flattened file, but those inside Targets are not performed until that Target is run.  And then is the Target done once or batched (if the Task lines inside the target is batched, but the target itself is not, it can be confusing that the properties are only set once but it looks like it's being called multiple times)

Comment: Thanks for reference to the MSBuildExplorer3. Its UI is quite hard to use, but since it's opensource I added logging to file and I can really see that it finds the assignment place.

Comment: Sounds like a good improvement.  I found the display text rather small with aliasing problems, like reading a smudged newspaper.

Comment: Unfortunately MSBuildExplorer3 hasn't been updated in 9 years and seems to be incompatible with modern msbuild files. The preprocess flag still works and is still useful though.

Answer (score 0):

`/v:diag` will dump all property values at the beginning of the console log (not file log) but won't tell you where they came from, i.e. project, imports, environment, command line arguments, etc. Run `msbuild Foo.csproj /pp:Foo.pp.csproj` instead, that'll resolve all imports and you can read the `.pp.csproj` file to find your property and the comment above will tell you what imported project defined it and its location.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to resolve my problem. Though debugging did not work for some reason, I has a very similar correct project and by comparison has found the place where it should be defined.